# How can I programmatically change the default colors in AvalonEditor for c#

Tags: wpf, colors, highlighting, avalonedit

I need to know how to programmatically change the default colors in the AvalonEdit for WPF in c#.  I don't want to rewrite an entire highlighting rule set.

I have found the background and foreground, but not sure about the colorizing rules.

Default Colors:
[image]

Is there a way to access the rule(s) by name, and assign a new Color, or create a new Brush to override the default colors to match this below?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my example, I will change the default color of "Comment" in the default highlighting rule set "XML".

```
using ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.Highlighting;

    // Get a instance of the default rule set "XML"
    var highlighting = HighlightingManager.Instance.GetDefinition("XML");

    // Get Color Definition "Comment"
    var commentHighlighting = highlighting.NamedHighlightingColors.First(c => c.Name=="Comment");

    // Change the Foreground Color
    commentHighlighting.Foreground = new SimpleHighlightingBrush(Color.FromRgb(0xC0, 0xC0, 0xC0));

    // Set the syntaxHighlighting
    myTextEditor.SyntaxHighlighting=highlighting;
```

The names of the color definitions can be found in the *.xshd files of the default highlighting rule sets. You can find them [here](https://github.com/icsharpcode/AvalonEdit/tree/master/ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit/Highlighting/Resources).